# Get icon from an apk file

Tags: android, winforms, aapt

I'm developing an Winform application using aapt to get some info from apk file. I got the path of application icon, something like this: *res/drawable-mdpi/app_icon.png*
I want to get the icon from its path and push it to an ImageList. How can i do it?
Thanks advanced!

Comment: You can open it as an archive and get the icon.

Answer (score 6):

Get icon from APK file:

```
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/thinkandroidsimple/pam.apk");
String sourcePath = file.getPath();

if (sourcePath.endsWith(".apk")) {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                   .getPackageArchiveInfo(filePath, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        if(packageInfo != null) {
            ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
                appInfo.sourceDir = sourcePath;
                appInfo.publicSourceDir = sourcePath;
            }
            Drawable icon = appInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());
            Bitmap bmpIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
        }
    }
```

See details: [How to get Icon from APK files in Android](http://thinkandroidsimple.blogspot.com/2014/01/android-how-to-get-icon-from-apk-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use WinRar/WinZip or equivalent to open the apk file (as you would for a .zip file) and extract the file from that path.

Answer (score 0):

See the following code may be help full to you

```
   public Drawable getFullResDefaultActivityIcon() {
            return getFullResIcon(Resources.getSystem(), android.R.mipmap.sym_def_app_icon);
        }

public Drawable getFullResIcon(Resources resources, int iconId) {
    Drawable d;
    try {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        int iconDpi = activityManager.getLauncherLargeIconDensity();
        d = resources.getDrawableForDensity(iconId, iconDpi);
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        d = null;
    }

    return (d != null) ? d : getFullResDefaultActivityIcon();
}

public Drawable getFullResIcon(String packageName, int iconId) {
    Resources resources;
    try {
        resources = mContext.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        resources = null;
    }
    if (resources != null) {
        if (iconId != 0) {
            return getFullResIcon(resources, iconId);
        }
    }
    return getFullResDefaultActivityIcon();
}

public Drawable getFullResIcon(ResolveInfo info) {
    return getFullResIcon(info.activityInfo);
}

public Drawable getFullResIcon(ActivityInfo info) {
    Resources resources;
    try {
        resources = mContext.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(info.applicationInfo);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        resources = null;
    }
    if (resources != null) {
        int iconId = info.getIconResource();
        if (iconId != 0) {
            return getFullResIcon(resources, iconId);
        }
    }
    return getFullResDefaultActivityIcon();
}

private Drawable getAppIcon(ResolveInfo info) {
    return getFullResIcon(info.activityInfo);
}
```